# What are those patterns found on the surface of wooden furniture? Are those growth rings of trees?

Tags: botany

This image can give a suitable example for the above question.

[image]

Comment: Which pattern the long lines are the separations between the individual boards.

Comment: *or; The streaks present on the top face of the table.

Comment: that is what I was talking about.

Comment: Just checking: you mean wood grain? As seen in https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Wood_grain#/media/File:16_wood_samples.jpg? (This shows a 4x4 grid of wood samples, each one shows a different wood grain pattern.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thees cut on any angle will reveal growth patterns; not all wood grows exactly the same. Some kinds grow straight and have a very even grain, at the other end is the "black gum", the grain of which seems to follow no organized pattern (it's almost impossible to split.)

Without a close up, it's hard to say exactly what's going on with your table.

Some woods, because of their grain and even density, take up stain very evenly and uniformly. An example would be oak. Some woods take up stain more irregularly, an example being maple.

Your table, though (all this is speculation since there's not a close up or head on view) looks like an example of blotchy stain uptake.

This is an example of blothcy staining wood:

[image]

If you look carefully at the grain, you can see that's not the only cause of uneven uptake. Some blotchiness is due to not sanding the table down finely enough. Some is due to the uneven density of the wood. See that diagonal scratch? It takes up color regardless of the grain. As do the ends of the boards.

Your table is made up of younger trees (you could see growth rings on the edge) which will give you more uneven uptake, plus it's a blotchy job. So, the answer is yes and no. Or, a qualified yes.